# Подключение к базе данных, используя объектно-ориентированный подход

Tags: ооп, php, mysql

Изучаю ООП.

Вот так я обычно подключаюсь к базе данных:

```
<?php  

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('bdname', $db);    
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM таблица WHERE id=2', $db);    
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);    
echo $row[image];

?>
```

Подскажите, как подключиться к базе данных к таблице с помощью ООП?

В инете искал учебные материалы на тему ООП и MYSQL в php, не смог найти.

Если есть, скиньте ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала изучаем [PHP:PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo), потом когда прониклись и осознали, что не совсем удобно и много повторяющегося кода, гуглим: "PDO обертки" или "PDO wrapper", далее постигаем дзень и пишим свою обертку.

Answer (score 1):

Файл информации о БД, например db-info.php

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "demo";
$database = "my_database";
```

Страница к которой мы хотим подключить БД, например index.php

```
include("db-info.php");
$link = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
if(!mysql_select_db($database)) die(mysql_error());
```

Все теперь мы можем на странице index.php делать любой запрос в базу данных, например достать всю информацию о пользователях

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$name = $r['name'];
```

Теперь переменная $name будет выбирать первое попавшееся имя какого нибудь юзера с таблицы `users`

Ну вот так это все выглядело бы

```
<?php
    include("db-info.php");
    $link = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
    if(!mysql_select_db($database)) die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $name = $r['name'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        //сдесь содержимое хэдэра
    </head>
<body>
     <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Ну конечно не обязательно весь PHP скрипт писать в начало страницы можно и поаккуратней сделать например через include(" файл.php ");

Comment: `die(mysql_error())` - плохая практика для продакшна.

Comment: Почему плохая ??? Вобщем то можно в место mysql_error вывести просто сообщение об ошибке, типа "база данных не доступна".

Comment: @Berserk, лучше либо вкладывать в `try-catch`, либо кидать исключение и ловить его уже просто глобальным обработчиком. Так гибче в настройке отображения ошибок.

Comment: А можно примерчик ?

Answer (score 0):

Класс:

```
class Base {
      function conn() { // подключение к БД
        mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
        mysql_select_db('bdname'); 
      }
}
```

Работа с БД:

```
$object = new Base(); // создаем объект
$object->conn(); // подключаемся к БД
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM таблица WHERE id=2 ');    
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($result);    
echo $row[image];
```

Comment: это уже даже не смешно.

Comment: Последние три строчки это не ООП.

Comment: @Андрей2 т.е. вы в серьез рассматриваете написание обертки для mysql_* функций?

Answer (score 0):

Это вообще не ООП. Нужно создать конструктор и деструктор, вот пример из рабочего кода:

```
class main {

    function __construct() {
        //Создаем свойство содержащее объект MySQLi
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database, $port, $socket);
    }

    //Некий метод
    public function someMethod() {
        //Пример использования (через свойство)
        $sql = "SELECT
                  `date_add`,
                  `date_out`
                FROM
                  `vkb_bans_ip`
                WHERE
                  `active`='1' AND `ip`=?";
        $query = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('s', $ip);
        $query->execute();
    }
    function __destruct() {
        $mysqli->close();
    }
}
```